# Is it possible that users running Excel negatively impacts an app that uses Excel Interop code?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I created an Excel Interop app that is used by a few internal users.

One noted that my app doesn't work right when she is simultaneously using Excel; at first I thought this was a coincidence/superstition, but then I found [a reference](http://www.resolvinghere.com/sm/exception-on-opening-new-excel-workbook-while-running-an-application-created-using.shtml) that indicates that running Excel at the same time as an Excel Interop app may indeed prove problamatic.

Is this really so - should I advise them all to quit Excel before using my app?